# In Chrome Dev tools, why is this css background-color faded out but not crossed out?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, google-chrome-devtools

I have a couple questions below.  I have a background on my menu bar that is white until way down below on the page, I remove a class="xxxxxx" from an element.  The menu bar then turns black and I am so confused as to why changing a style way way down the page of a section html element modifies the color of the navigation bar.  I bring up Chrome Dev Tools and peak at the menu section to look for how it gets it's color.  The background-color is the VERY last line in this picture and is 'faded' but not crossed out.

[image]

The background-color in chrome dev tools shows white like I want but the menu is black.  I can verify that if I add element.style { background-color: white }, it turns back white again.

Questions:

1. What does faded out mean in Chrome Dev Tools(vs. crossed out)?
2. Any ideas/guess or things I can try as to why a menu div background would turn black on me?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: (1) Have you already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265555/what-does-it-mean-when-a-css-rule-is-grayed-out-in-chromes-element-inspector), which covers inheritance & default styles?  (2) If you are able to provide a pen showing your current code, it may be easier to debug point .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome developer tools Style tab showing faded CSS definition, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784001/chrome-developer-tools-style-tab-showing-faded-css-definition-why)

Comment: From the screenshot, your navbar doesn't have any background associated with it. can you put up a code snippet reproducing the issue. ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak That doesn't seem to be the same since text-align is NOT faded while background is faded.  I read that post(and it was good!! so thanks) however, how in the world are half of my attributes in body applied(not faded) and the others are not applied(ie. they are faded)

Comment: ohhh, @TS89 , ,that post explained the faded out better than the other link!!  nice!

Comment: @DeanHiller text-align is not faded because it is being inherited, you can see margin being faded out because it's not an inheritable property, That is exactly what is being said in both answers, and i don't understand your second comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so some parallax.js was installed and ripping that out for some reason fixed it all.  I think it dynamically set styling and such up AND that styling for some reason is not showing in chrome's css stuff making it very very hard to debug.  Once I uninstalled parallax, chrome worked as expected and I could easily debug the css. (NOT sure if this is a chrome bug/issue or a parallax issue).