# trying to understand when inner div automatically inherits from parent div

Tags: html, css

I've a simple css file:

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 33%;
}
```

and simple HTML with few divs:

```
<div class="center">
  <div> some text here </div>
</div>
```

Now I was expecting the inner div to inherit the margin and width properties from parent but that didn't happen. I'm trying to re-learn CSS in a proper way so interested in these kinds of seemingly minor but important things. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only certain CSS properties inherit.

I've borrowed a list from @Blender on this thread. **[Which CSS properties are inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-styles-are-inherited)**

```
azimuth
border-collapse
border-spacing
caption-side
color
cursor
direction
elevation
empty-cells
font-family
font-size
font-style
font-variant
font-weight
font
letter-spacing
line-height
list-style-image
list-style-position
list-style-type
list-style
orphans
pitch-range
pitch
quotes
richness
speak-header
speak-numeral
speak-punctuation
speak
speak-rate
stress
text-align
text-indent
text-transform
visibility
voice-family
volume
white-space
widows
word-spacing
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/vEaZb/)

```
<div class="willbeInheritedDiv childDiv">
    some content
</div>

.willbeInheritedDiv
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.childDiv
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

technically this is not inheritance but you can provide relationship between div classes and in your example you were trying to inherit width, so this can be helpful