# How to avoid copy-paste when styling web components from the outside?

Tags: css, css-selectors, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Say, I am using a <core-input> inside my web component, and I want to style the <input> element inside the <core-input>.
For that I would need to do

```
<style>
  :host::shadow input {
    background-color: green
  }
</style>
```

Now, the selector is okay, but I don't want to define the style properties here, because I have a CSS file made by a designer guy, that looks like this:

```
.input-like-things {
  background-color: green
}
```

On the other hand, the designer guy is not going to produce almost identical CSS files for each web component I use that has something looking like an input.

How do I correctly apply the ".input-like-things" class (or its contents) to the <input> field inside <core-input>?

I am not considering /deep/ as an option.

I created a custom component that can copy the contents of the ".input-like-things" class into the <style> tag, and that works, but only in Chrome. I could not get it to work in Firefox as long as data binding does not work inside <style> in ShadowDOM polyfill.

Help?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-style? It also allows bindings in `<style>` :)

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, I was extending it to copy the style. But I couldn't get whatever style I made dynamically work in Firefox.
Could you detail how core-style can help solve the problem?
In core-style, I would still need to give a specific rule name like
<style>:host::shadow input { ... } </style>, wouldn't I?

Comment: You won't be able to target nodes in another element's shadow dom without rewriting selectors or modifying the element definition itself (by injecting styles or otherwise). Styles that are [inheritable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-styles-are-inherited) may work, but the style scoping Shadow DOM provides is both a blessing and curse

Comment: You can style the content of the shadow host. So the `<input>` element could be declared and styled in the main DOM, then projected in the shadow DOM. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-projection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shadow DOM CSS Styling from outside is not working in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178469/shadow-dom-css-styling-from-outside-is-not-working-in-google-chrome)