# Shadow DOM CSS Styling from outside is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, polymer, shadow-dom

I am using `polymer`'s `paper-action-dialog` and `paper-button` in my web page. There are two paper-buttons in a paper-action-dialog. I want to style those paper-buttons from outside (main html). I have written `CSS` styles in `shadow DOM` notation. These styles are working fine in Firefox browser but not behaving correctly in `Google-chrome` browser. What should I do in order to get that work in chrome.?

Mark up

```
<paper-action-dialog class="ask" backdrop autoCloseDisabled=true heading="Heading!">
  <p>This is the sample paragraph.</p>
  <paper-button  autofocus class="test" affirmative>Edit</paper-button>
  <paper-button  autofocus class="test" affirmative>OK</paper-button>
</paper-action-dialog>
```

CSS

```
paper-action-dialog::shadow paper-button.test{
            font-size: small;
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Answer lies in comment:

Selector should be `overlay-host::shadow paper-button.test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should investigate the DOM (<kbd>F12</kbd> or context menu inspect element). The HTML for the actual dialog is added somewhere to the body tag not within the `<paper-action-dialog>`. You have to adapt the selectors accordingly.

Comment: I will investigate this. But then how come is it working in firefox? I even deployed this to my android device using cordova and still it was working. I also tried accessing element in a way it is done here -http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/demo.html

Comment: Because Firefox has no shadow DOM. The demo page shows that the actual dialog is added to `<body><core-overlay-layer><overlay-host>#shadow<paper-dialog>`. Because the element is named `<paper-dialog>` here as well it is working in Firefox (no scoped CSS). If you add the CSS to your `index.html` and change the selector to `* /deep/ paper-action-dialog::shadow paper-button.test` or `overlay-host::shadow paper-action-dialog::shadow paper-button.test` it will probably work in Chrome too. I have no working `paper-action-dialog` demo, I just derived the selectors above from the `paper-dialog` demo.