# Why there is no inheritance in CSS

Tags: css

In Chrome DevTools I noticed one thing, which I cannot understand.
If I set only width and height to a body in CSS - then div doesn`t inherited any property.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    text
  </div>
</body>
```

In this case in DevTools we can see - div doesn`t have any inherited properties from body.
But if I add font-size to a body - div inherited font-size, width and height property.

Help me to understand, what is going on?

Comment: CSS uses a box model, you might want to read up on it

Comment: It is inherited. Try to change the `width:100px` instead of `100%` and check div is now only `100px`

Comment: @SatejS This has nothing to do with the box model.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, got confused.

Answer (score 4):

CSS properties are either *inherited* or not. `width` is not inherited. `font-size` is. For information on inheritance, see [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance).

The MDN page for each CSS property, such as [this one for `font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size), will tell you whether the property is inherited or not.

Hence, applying `font-size` to body will cause (by default) child elements to have that same size. In contrast, applying `width` to body will not apply that width to the children (which would not make any sense).

Answer (score 1):

The width and height values are set to auto by default. If you want to use the height applied in your parent to the child then you need to explicitly inherit them:

```
body{
  height: 100%;
}
body > div{/*otherwise, it was auto height*/
  height: 100%; /*Or, inherit*/
}
```

---

## The Fact:

From the [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) the [width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width) and [height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height) are defined **inherited** to **NO**.

You can see the list of properties that are inherited in css [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) and  [here in other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited).

> azimuth, border-collapse, border-spacing, caption-side, color, cursor, direction, elevation, empty-cells, font-family, font-size, font-style, font-variant, font-weight, font, letter-spacing, line-height, list-style-image, list-style-position, list-style-type, list-style, orphans, pitch-range, pitch, quotes, richness, speak-header, speak-numeral, speak-punctuation, speak, speech-rate, stress, text-align, text-indent,  text-transform
>       visibility
>       voice-family
>       volume
>       white-space
>       widows
>       word-spacing