# Difference between when applying tbody td:nth-of-type(3){ border-bottom-color: transparent; } and tr.noborder td{ border-bottom: transparent; } in CSS

Tags: html, css

**First Scenario:**

```css
h1{
 text-align: center;
}

td{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-right: 1px solid gray;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 
}

table{
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

tbody td:nth-of-type(3){

 border-right-color: transparent;

}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(3){

 border-bottom-color: transparent;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/tic.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<table>
<tbody>
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Second Scenario:**

```css
h1{
 text-align: center;
}

td{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-right: 1px solid gray;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 
}

table{
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

tbody td:nth-of-type(3){

 border-right-color: transparent;

}

tr.noborder td{
 border-bottom: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/tic.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<table>
<tbody>
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 
 
   <tr class="noborder">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

For the first scenario, I am not getting the correct output. I am not sure that why the property `tbody td:nth-of-type(3) { border-bottom-color: transparent; }` is not getting applied even though its specificity is more than `td`.

For the second scenario, I added a class in HTML and the results are correct while for the first scenario it is incorrect.

Could you please help me in making changes to the CSS property in the first scenario without adding any class and id?

I am new to HTML and CSS. Thank you so much for your concern in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are applying border to `td` not to `tr`, use `tbody tr:nth-of-type(3) td` to get transparent border like you wanted, see below

```css
h1{
 text-align: center;
}

td{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-right: 1px solid gray;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 
}

table{
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

tbody td:nth-of-type(3){

 border-right-color: transparent;

}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(3) td{

 border-bottom-color: transparent;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/tic.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<table>
<tbody>
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 
 
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I have more question. So if we apply "tbody tr:nth-of-type(3) {border-bottom-color: transparent;}" , why this style is not getting applied to all the descendants of third tr.Why it is important to specify the td after tr?

Comment: Because border-color is inherited from the parent, for example if you apply font-size on tr, it will be inherited but not every properties. you can find out more inheritable properties here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited

Comment: But the border-color property is not inheritable as you can see in the link https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-color-properties . I can conclude that border-color is not inheritable that is why we need to specifically specify the td while background property is inheritable that means even we do not apply the td, background property is being applied to all the descendants of tr.

Comment: Hi PankajChibhrani, sorry it was a typo, I meant to say border-color property is not inherited