# HTML tag inherit its default styles from browser or OS?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

If i apply `line-height : inherit` on `html` element then from where does it inherit the `line-height` value. Because apparently html has no parent from which it can inherit its styles. Does it inherit from the system (OS)?

Comment: 0


If i apply "line-height : inherit" on HTML element then from where it inherits the "line-height" value. Because apparently html has no parent from which it can inherit its styles. Does it inherits from the system (OS)?

Comment: Can you please show your code so that we can get context?

Comment: That code is very big around 20 pages in html. I can show u a demo code:
<html style="line-height:inherit">
  <body>
<p style="line-height:inherit">Hello world</p>
</body>

Comment: @Corné IMO the OP is asking for a query. I don't think the OP needs to post some code for this.

Comment: it has no other element to inherit, it takes browser default value. we cant say OS becuase it varies from browser to browser mainly.

Comment: How can i see the browser default values for all the styles. if "line-height : inherit" is there then i want to see the numeric value so that i can change accordingly

Comment: Why are you applying `line-height` to the `html`? And if you have to do it like this, why not set a value?

Comment: See i am doing bug fix work. I wanted to retrieve the same line-height value that is already there in the document. So i need to know what is the current line-height value in pixels so that i can change it in entire document.

Comment: Hello there, as far as I know, <html> is the root element, and the root element gets the initial value from the browser only, there is no use in applying that to the html tag. Instead set the line-height to individual elements, use `vh` or specify height in terms or percentage. For beginners, I recommend learning bootstrap

Comment: The default `line-height` value is `normal` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_line-height

Comment: yes it is default but is there a way i can see its numeric value like we can see the numeric value of width in offsetWidth and height in offsetHeight properties.

Comment: No, you can not directly look up what numeric value `normal` corresponds to. You can get the calculated _pixel_ value form your browser dev tools. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values shows you that Firefox uses `1.2` for `normal`, and if you check the actual specification, you’ll see that browsers should use a value between 1.0 and 1.2 for normal, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

Comment: @04FS Got it. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: To be pedantic, Firefox uses the value 1.2 _rounded to whole pixels_. For a font size of 16px, `normal` results in 19px, while `1.2` results in 19.2px. Not sure about Chrome; Chrome doesn't show a size in px in its developer tools when the value is `normal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways an element can have some specific style:

- css applied by your css
- css default style for each element this values are applied by default, you can check some default values [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)
- css applied by the browser, each browser puts its on default styles, [this article](http://www.dev-hq.net/html-css/21--default-browser-styles) can help you to normalize this problem.

**HTML tag inherit its default styles from browser or OS?**

it inherit its default styles from the browser.

Comment: Ok that answers my first question that from where HTML tag inherits its default styles. So if i have to change my "line-height" for entire document then i only have to  assign new line height (numeric value in pixels) to my HTML tag and inherit that wherever i want in entire document.

Comment: yes all the descendant elements will inherit from html, consider that not all the properties are inherited you can check this list https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612360/2894798