# Why does setting margin remove list indentation

Tags: html, css

I have created a nested list in html.

Why does setting margin: 0 using the *{} selector remove the list indention but not if I use the body selector?

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Resume
    <ul>
      <li>Experience</li>
      <li>Skills</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Interests
    <ul>Photography</ul>
    <ul>Favourites</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because `*` represent all element, and `body{}` just the body. The padding is in the `<ul>` element

Comment: What @Roy said, plus the fact that `padding` is [not an inherited property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited). The padding you set for the `body` element applies only to that element, not to its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk `*` means all, so when you put a property in **(all)** it basically styles **all** the elements in your HTML body

But when you choose only to style the `body` you don't change anything's style but `body`

You can read the answers [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-HTML-and-body-elements-in-CSS-Resets) for more details

Comment: but * have lowest `Specificity` so there is applied in them element there havnt same property mentioned in *

Comment: @NishargShah Sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: @NishargShah you're right, * has lowest specificity, but that doesn't matter here, as the "body" selector doesn't select ul's

Comment: @JonasGrumann Thanks for your comment, now I understand what he says :D