# Which CSS Properties penetrate the Shadow Root of a WebComponent?

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there an official list maintained, with up to date details on the CSS Properties which penetrate the `Shadow Root` of a `WebComponent`?

I gather that the following:

- `color`
- `line-height`
- `font-family`
- `font-size`
- `font-weight`

all do, but there must be at least a dozen more, are there?

Comment: I would say all the *inherited* properties

Comment: Thanks - in which case this page might be (somewhat) useful: [Which CSS properties are inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited). It's from 2011 though, so it will also be substantially out of date.

Comment: Aha. I think I understand what I was confused about before. For _shadow-root_ penetration to occur, there must be i) a parent element outside the _shadow-root_ from which properties may be inherited AND ii) an element inside the _shadow-root_ which may inherit properties AND iii) an inheritable property. e.g. if there is a `<p>` inside the _shadow-root_ and a global stylesheet declares: `p {color: red;}` then that `<p>` _won't_ be `red`. But if the same global stylesheet declares: `body {color: red;}` then it will.