# global style doesn't apply on all components in StencilJs

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, stenciljs

I'm using StencilJs. The problem is I can't use global styles inside `shadow=true` components.
In [this section of Docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling#global-styles) it explicitly says we can use it for adding font-face and css-reset. But I'm not able to use this feature. it only applies to components with `shadow=false`

Here is my global.style.scss

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  &:hover, &:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

in stencil.config.ts I have

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'areas-power',
  globalStyle: 'src/assets/styles/global.style.scss',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements',
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme',
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null, // disable service workers
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    sass()
  ]
};
```

I also added its link to index.html file. style only apply to `body` tag. it doesn't apply on buttons inside other components. How I can add shared css-reset and font-face to all components in Stencil?

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work. The docs state that using `:root` allows properties to pass through to shadow DOM. `button` is not `:root` so it behaves like any other global style. `font-face` will work because it is an "inherited" property, so the component host element will inherit it from DOM, and the component's shadow elements will inherit it from the host. The normal rules of shadow DOM and CSS property inheritance always apply. See this post for information about inheritable properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612360/9226213. It may also be helpful to know that the default value for background-color is transparent, so although it is not inheriting from parent elements, it would appear to have the same background color.