Styling issue in Blazor/Razor components when using .razor.css
I'm facing an issue when trying to apply styles to Blazor/Razor components when I move the styles to a separate CSS file. In my project, I define styles in a .razor component, and when applying styles directly in this file, the styles are correctly applied to the HTML elements within that component and its child components.
However, when I move the styles to a separate .razor.css file and try to include it in the HTML, some styles are not applied correctly to the HTML elements. Specifically, the color style is applied correctly, but the border style is not.
Could someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix this issue?
Here's a simplified example of the code:
Case 1 (Ok)
In the Test1.razor file:
<div class="aeae">
    <h5>Test1 Title</h5>
</div>

In the Home.razor file:
<div class="aeae">
    <h5>Home</h5>
    <Test1 />
</div>

<style>
    .aeae {
        border: 1px solid red;
        color: blue;
    }
</style>

The result is that the "Test1 Title" text is displayed in blue, and the border displayed in red (OK).
Case 2 (??)
In the Home.razor file:
<div class="aeae">
    <h5>Home</h5>
    <Test1 />
</div>
/* Removed <style> from Home.razor */
- <style>
-     .aeae {
-         border: 1px solid red;
-         color: blue;
-     }
- </style>

In the Home.razor.css file:
.aeae {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: blue;
}

The result is that the "Test1 Title" text is displayed in blue, but the red border is not applied to the elements in Test1.razor.
So, obviosly Home.razor.css file is being included correctly in the HTML and if there are no syntax errors. However, I can't understand why the color style is applied correctly but the border style isn't.

CSS isolation only support for the component itself but not the child components. In case1, class aeae is applied both on the parent and child component, but in case2, aeae only applied for the parent component so that it both has blue font and red border. But since this is a div and the child component is also a div, so the child component also used blue font, but border style can't be inherited, if you test  with padding/margin, you might see they are not inherited as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited

This is by design of CSS Isolation, and the symptom is due to class .aeae isn't applied to the child component resulting from CSS Isolation.

The styles defined in Example.razor.css are only applied to the
rendered output of the Example component.

The reason for child component to have blue font is due to style inherited. The parent div having red border and blue font, but border color can't be inherited while font color can.
Comparing with the 2 cases, we can see in case2, CSS isolation makes the child doesn't use .aeae indeed, child component just inherit the  parent style.


If we want the child component to be applied the same class, we need ::deep. More details can be seen here.
If we define codes below in ParentComponent.razor.css, then we can see the components rendered like the CASE1.
.aeae {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: blue;
}
::deep .aeae {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: blue;
}



Got it. Thanks for this help!
I don't think I've ever seen this "inherited from" in DevTools before.
It will help me understand better some situations.

thanks for your reply, do you have any other issues on this question? @Guttizin

No, thanks! That's was really helpful.
